# meaning of "transverse"

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

The Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary defines **transverse** as *placed across something* and gives the following example sentence and synonym:

> A transverse bar joins the two posts.
>
> -> Synonym: diagonal

I am wondering whether **diagonal** and **transverse**  would mean the same if the former were used in the example sentence.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Yes, there can be used interchangeably in the sentence: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=transverse+bar%2Cdiagonal+bar&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctransverse%20bar%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdiagonal%20bar%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @user5768790 They're absolutely not interchangeable. The [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/transverse) even goes so far as to state transverse is 90° [which I wouldn't have insisted on, merely 'crosswise'], whereas diagonal, if you're going to insist on specifying an angle, is going to be more like 45°.

Comment: All diagonals are transverse, but not all that is transverse is diagonal.  Not all uses of transverse involve perpendicularity.The word is given a prescriptive definition in  certain domains.

Comment: Are all vertical and horizontal lines transverse?

Answer (score 2):

Although they are synonyms 'transverse' and ' diagonal' do not necessarily mean the same thing. Without knowing exactly what the writer meant when they chose the word 'transverse' to describe the bar,it is not possible to determine if the writer intended 'transverse' to mean 'diagonal'.

Common synonyms of transverse, excluding diagonal,  include:

- At an angle
- Oblique
- Horizontal
- At an angle of 90° to something else

If the writer meant that the bar joins the two posts but runs at an oblique angle between them (i.e. neither parallel or at 90°), then diagonal would be an acceptable replacement for transverse.

If the writer meant that the bar joins the two posts but runs horizontally between them, intersecting them at an angle of 90°, then diagonal would not be an acceptable replacement for transverse.

Comment: If one post is attached upright to the ground and the other is attached to the ground at a slant, can the transverse bar that joins the two be called a diagonal bar?

Comment: @Apollyon I have a science background, so I tend to think of transverse as meaning something that meets something else at an angle of 90°, e.g. a transverse wave. So, I would not normally regard a bar joined in the way you mentioned to be a transverse bar, but I could think of it as being diagonal.

Comment: @Apollyon I'll preface this by saying I'm not a native speaker of English, but we have the same terms in my first language. *Diagonal* usually means (i.e., outside mathematics) "slanted" or "at an angle". Something that's placed diagonally needn't even connect anything. [This](https://tinyurl.com/y949te7b) is an example of a diagonal line. Something *transversal* connects two *sides*. Usually these sides are on the right and on the left. It doesn't matter if the sides themselves are slanted a bit (as in your example). So a bar connecting upright and slanted posts in any fashion is transversal.

Comment: Actually, something transversal doesn't have to connect two things; I was merely describing the meaning of the word in the context of your example. A transversal bar can just lie across something (perhaps just air, but it usually implies some two sides, two ends). Of course, I disagree with James's comment because I have no idea how they were able to surmise that the connecting bar is placed diagonally. It's definitely transversal but we can't tell whether it's diagonal based on just what you said.

Comment: A transversal bar can connect the two sides of a V-shaped construction to form something akin to the letter A (when turned upside down), with the transversal bar in the middle being slanted a little, or being perfectly horizontal as in the mentioned glyph. Also, the transversal bar needn't necessarily connect the two sides of the V perfectly; its ends might well be sticking out a bit. However, as noted in the comment by the user Tetsujin, it'd normally be understood as horizontal.

Comment: @ userr2684291  Can you please tell me where I "surmise[d] that the connecting bar is placed diagonally".  I said that "I **could think** of it as being diagonal", not that I **thought** that **it was diagonal**.  I can also think of ways in which the bar would not be diagonal, or where it would be diagonal to one post and not the other, but I saw no reason to complicate the answer by going into such details.